# prepareForSegue not called when load and register nib for custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Here is the code I use to display a custom cell (I load from an nib file):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"BR1LineCellRightImg" bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"BR1LineCellRightImg"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    BR1LineCellRightImg *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BR1LineCellRightImg"];
    //extra code
    return cell;
}
```

However, the method prepareForSegue will never be called, although I have setup a segue of a prototype cell in Storyboard with custom class and identifier is "BR1LineCellRightImg"

Comment: If you are using a prototype cell in the storyboard then you shouldn't register the nib file For the reuse identifier - it will override any configuration you have in the storyboard. You should layout your prototype cell directly in the storyboard.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think I have to go with your suggestion

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a prototype cell in the storyboard then you shouldn't register the nib file for the reuse identifier - it will override any configuration you have in the storyboard.

You should layout your prototype cell directly in the storyboard and then the Storyboard process will register the reuse identifier for you.